# Primefaces in electron

Tags: jsf, primefaces, electron

Is it possible to run a `Primefaces application` in `Electron`?

I tried the following code

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600,show: false, acceptFirstMouse : true , webPreferences: { allowRunningInsecureContent : true,webSecurity : false,plugins : true} })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/my-app')

  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
   mainWindow.show()
 });

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

it`s open a window with the Login screen. But any Primefaces components e.g. p:autocomplete won´t work.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Can you run jsf in it?

Comment: JSF work totally fine!

Comment: PrimeFaces runs where any recent JSF version runs. And _"p:autocomplete won't work" is sort of vague. I only see a 'browser' emulation that loads a webapp. Please investigate way more... What does the electron 'console' tell you?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As far as I know, electron is supposed to give you the chance to write JS+HTML+CSS applications to be run on desktop. That means being able to run them offline. With JSF, being a server side oriented framework, the server performs the HTML rendering. It would only work if you embed the whole server in the application. Does it make sense? Think about it.